# Ionic: two buttons in navbar

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using this code for my header navigation:

```html
<ion-view title="Events" hide-back-button="true">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
...
</ion view>
```

How to add second button to right side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```html
<ion-view title="Events" hide-back-button="true">

 <ion-nav-buttons side="left"> <!-- left -->
   <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
 </ion-nav-buttons>

 <ion-nav-buttons side="right"> <!-- right -->
   <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
 </ion-nav-buttons>

</ion view>
```

Comment: Can two buttons be added in the same direction for example both in `right`??

Comment: can i added more then two button on nav bar ?

Comment: I am very much new to ionic and want to show two nav-button on right, can anybody help, please